# Extract the price and sign it up for variable using javascript and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I am using node-binance-api
the follwoing function bring me all details of my last order:

```
binance.trades(“BNBUSD”, (error, trades, symbol) => {
console.info(symbol+" last order:", trades);
}, {limit:1});
```

How can extract only a the price and sign it up for a variable?

I get the following details:

```
{
symbol: ‘BNBUSD’,
id: -------,
orderId:-----------,
orderListId: -1,
price: ‘-----------’,
qty: ‘---------’,
quoteQty: ‘------’,
commission: ‘0.00105000’,
commissionAsset: ‘BNB’,
time: ----------,
isBuyer: true,
isMaker: false,
isBestMatch: true
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're getting an array of trades, which means there'll be multiple prices.

If you need a collection of prices of all trades, you could assign those prices to a `prices` variable like so:

```js
binance.trades("BNBUSD", (error, trades, symbol) => {
  let prices = trades.map(trade => trade.price);
  // ... do something with `prices` here...
}, {limit:1});
```

At that point, `prices` will be an array of numbers (something like `[1, 2.5, 0.7, 3, ...]` depending on what the prices are).

Comment: thank for your help. I receive the following "SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target"

Comment: That's weird because I'm not doing any destructuring... First, try turning the curly quotes around `BNBUSD` into straight ones (i.e. `"` instead of `“`). That may not be related to the error you're getting but it will definitely lead to trouble down the road.

Comment: I received the following:

Comment: binance.trades(BNBUSD, (error, trades, symbol) => {
               ^

ReferenceError: BNBUSD is not defined

Comment: You need quotes around `BNBUSD`. Just not curly ones.